# WPF System Tray application many appearances

Tags: wpf, system-tray

I have a system tray application developed using WPF, .NET4.0.  When I start this application 100s of system tray icon for the application starts appearing even though a single process is present in task manager.  Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks & Regards,
Vinit

Comment: You're adding too many icons.   Use the debugger to find out why your code is running hundreds of times.

Comment: If you mouse-over the extra icons, do they vanish?

Comment: Constructor of the application was getting called continuously which was resulting in creation of multiple system tray icons

Answer (score 1):

Constructor of the application was getting called continuously which was resulting in creation of multiple system tray icons

Comment: Did you find out why this happened? Something must have been making the constructor calls...